# Coudn't load JSON while calling api in Swift

Tags: json, macos, swift

I have my own api for an application. I was trying to call the api and i need to get the json data as the response. Here is my code

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var EmailText: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var PasswordText: NSSecureTextField!
@IBAction func signin(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("email is \(EmailText.objectValue) and Password is \(PasswordText.objectValue)")

    var url : String = "https:username:password@api.example.co/api/v3/auth/token/"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            println("\(jsonResult)")
        } else {
            println("Couldn't load json")
        }


    })
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
}
```

The jsonResult should give me the apikey as the json data.

But the else condition was showing for me while running the mac app. As I was very new for the swift and also for building the mac app, I was not able to overcome with this.

Comment: Have not forget to set the JSON header or something like that? Have you an error? Do you have any response?

I suggest you to do request with Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire created by the AfNetworking.

Comment: Thanks for the link @houguetpierre .I have given the json header and the response i was getting was nil. Is there any related links like this? Please help

Comment: Have you try to play the request in a browser or with advance rest client a chrome plugin? Is is possible to see the JSON waited? Maybe it's not a dictionary, and the data converter return nil.

Comment: So what errors are reported??

Comment: check the error and also print the data - bet it is a html page

Comment: What's the error? It could be pretty useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the duplicate of this [error: Error Domain=HTTPTask Code=404 "page not found" UserInfo=0x608000228720 {NSLocalizedDescription=page not found}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521212/error-error-domain-httptask-code-404-page-not-found-userinfo-0x608000228720) I think. Anyways as I said for that question please check below.

You are using the format `user@email.com:password@api.domain/com/....` which works while you are working in Javascript or Jquery.

In Swift, it doesn't takes in the basic-auth. For the basic auth, we have to send with the encode string to the authentication url like:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "\(Email.stringValue):\(Password.stringValue)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    println("\(authString)")
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)



    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.domain.com/api/v2/auth/token/")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (let data, let response, let error) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
}
```

After then just print the data and see it will definitely meets your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @houguet pierre mentioned, you could use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), it will handle the JSON object if you get one, and also alert you if you don't. 
This code is the simplest case, and probably enough for what you need.

`Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
         .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, error) in
                  if error == nil {
                     println(JSON)
                   } else {
                     println(error.localizedDescription)
    }`