# error: Error Domain=HTTPTask Code=404 "page not found" UserInfo=0x608000228720 {NSLocalizedDescription=page not found}

Tags: json, macos, swift

As I am new for the Swift Programming Language. I am building the mac app. I have to integrate with my api by sending the httprequest to my api.

I am using the submodule SwiftHTTP for the http request.

Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

import SwiftHTTPOSX

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var EmailField: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var PasswordField: NSSecureTextField!

@IBAction func signin(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("email is \(EmailField.objectValue) and Password is \(PasswordField.objectValue)")

    var request = HTTPTask()
    request.GET("https:user@gmail.com:password@api.domain.co/api/v3/auth/token/", parameters: nil, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
        if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("response: \(response.responseObject)")
        }
        }, failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
            println("error: \(error)")
    })

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

}
```

Error:

```
error: Error Domain=HTTPTask Code=401 "accessed denied" UserInfo=0x60000002ae20 {NSLocalizedDescription=accessed denied}
```

Expected Output Description:

When I send request to the "http:user@gmail.com:password@api.domain.co/api/v3/auth/token", in the response I will get the apikey. But the above error killing me.

Comment: "When I send request to the "http:user@gmail.com:password@api.domain.co/api/v3/auth/token", in the response I will get the apikey." Where are you doing this, exactly? In a browser?

Comment: In the browser, I was getting the apikey in proper. But now I am doing this in the swift program building mac app. Here I was getting the above error which I have mentioned. @MattGibson

Comment: Your browser is interpreting the username and password in the URL for you and creating an HTTP basic auth header using them. Putting them in the URL like that is a trick that only some clients support, it's not part of a authorisation standard or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using the SwiftHTTP at all. And also you are using the format `user@email.com:password@api.domain/com/....` which works while you are working in Javascript or Jquery.

In Swift, it doesn't takes in the basic-auth. For the basic auth, we have to send with the encode string to the authentication url like:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "\(Email.stringValue):\(Password.stringValue)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    println("\(authString)")
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)



    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.domain.com/api/v2/auth/token/")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (let data, let response, let error) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
}
```

After then just print the data and see it will definitely meets your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that Apple's networking classes let you use the URL form of http basic auth, with the username and password in the URL. Have you found that documented anywhere?

Even if they do, you'd probably need to url-encode the username and password so that things like the "@" symbol you've got in the username don't trip things up. I'd actually expect the example URL you've provided to actually try to connect to "gmail.com" rather than "api.domain.co".

Personally, for HTTP basic auth, I instead construct a standard base64-encoded Authorization header to send along, rather than putting it in the URL. Here's a couple of fragments of my code to give you an example. Note that I set the Authorization header on a NSURLSessionConfiguration object so all requests made with that configuration get the header added automatically. Alternatively you can add the header using `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField` on each request.

```
private class func authorizationHeaderForEmailAddress(emailAddress: String, password: String) -> String? {
    let userColonPass = "\(emailAddress):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if let base64UserColonPass = userColonPass?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil) {
        return "Basic \(base64UserColonPass)" 
    }
    return nil
}

...

if let authHeader = SnapFeederAPI.authorizationHeaderForEmailAddress(emailAddress, password: password) {
    // Add this to the NSURLSessionConfiguration so it's sent automatically with
    // every request.
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authHeader]
} // Else there's a problem
```

Comment: Well, it's the only way to do basic auth, as far as I know. You need to provide the authorisation header. What's not "perfect"?